# spark: transpose more row on single row with more column

Tags: apache-spark

I have this situation in Spark

```
+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----------+-----------+
|month|years|id   |  category|sum(amount)|avg(amount)|
+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1  | 2015| id_1|     A    |   10000   |    2000   |
|  1  | 2015| id_1|     B    |   1000    |    100    |
|  1  | 2015| id_1|     C    |   2000    |    1000   |
+-----+-----+-----+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

and I would like to get this:

```
+-----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|                 |      category_A       |        category_B     |      category_C       | 
+-----+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|month|years|id   |sum(amount)|avg(amount)|sum(amount)|avg(amount)|sum(amount)|avg(amount)|
+-----+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1  | 2015| id_1|  10000    |    2000   |   1000    |    100    |   2000    |    1000   |
+-----+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution using dataframe and pivot:

```
df
  .groupBy($"month",$"years",$"id")
  .pivot("category")
  .agg(sum($"amount"),avg($"amount"))
```

It is possible a solution with rdd?